# I just arrived to the US with the F-2 (student's dependent) visa, can I get an ITIN?

Tags: united-states, tax-law, f1-visa, f2-visa

I just arrived to the US (from May 31 2021) and I want to get an ITIN. I have F-2 visa which depends on my wife's F-1 student visa. I want to know can I apply for ITIN just by filling out and sending the form W7 to the IRS or I must fill out other forms like 1040? Because this is the first time I am in the US and I don't have any income history in the US.

`EDIT:` I read the W7 form and between the options it provides, I think I must choose option "g" that says: **"Dependent/spouse of a nonresident alien holding a U.S. visa"**. But it also says: **"Caution: If you check box b, c, d, e, f, or g, you must file a U.S. federal tax return with Form W-7 unless you meet one of the exceptions"**.

Also my friend told me I must wait until Jan 2022 then I can fill form 1040 and attach it to form W7, then I can apply for ITIN at that time but I can not do that before Jan 2020. Is what he told me true? If so, there is no faster way I can get ITIN?

Comment: This seems like a question for [Expatriates.SE].

Answer (score -1):

Read https://studyinthestates.dhs.gov/students/individual-taxpayer-identification-number-itin

To apply for an ITIN, submit to the IRS:

• Form W-7, “Application for IRS Individual Taxpayer Identification Number”

• A certification letter (with applicant’s full name and SEVIS number)

• Copies of identity and foreign status documentation A copy of the Form I-20

• “Certificate of Eligibility for Nonimmigrant Student Status”

• Other required documentation to meet the Form W-7 application requirement

Form 1040 is a tax return; you have no need to file that, and can't, as you don't have any income.

Comment: Thanks for answer, please read also the EDIT part.

Comment: "Form 1040 is a tax return; you have no need to file that, and can't, as you don't have any income": you can file an income tax return and report zero income.

Comment: Also as I am not a student I don't know how to get the second and furth letters?